# Resize div in jquery from right to left

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I **want to animate and resize div tag from right to left**.

By default i have learnt from examples and found it resizes from left to right but as per project requirement we wish to have it in right to left order.

The code I have written is :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("button").click(function()
   {
      $("div#div1").animate({height:166},5000);
      $("div#div1").animate({width:800},5000);
   });
});
</script> 

<div id="div1" style="background:url(stripes.JPG);height:0px;width:0px;position:relative;" hidden="hidden">
```

This works well in left to right animation; please suggest similar approach where the div will resize from right to left.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's all a matter of your CSS. Have your animated element wrapped in a `position:relative` element, and set its CSS to `position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;`. Then youre animation will be displayed in the desired direction. See: http://jsfiddle.net/9SJ4Q/