# Is it possible to reveal the contents of a div from right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gifcy/bJJ5s/5/

On DOM ready I hide the image.

I could successfully reveal the image from left to right using animate function.

Can someone show how to reveal from right to left. What additional parameters need to used.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667143/resize-div-in-jquery-from-right-to-left/9667290#9667290

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this will work cross browser

```
#nature,
#nature img {
    float:right;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8zDk/

Answer (score 3):

Use jquery ui show() function

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#nature').hide();

    $('#animation').click(function() {
       $('#nature').show('slide', {direction: 'right'},1000);


    });
});   
​
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/bJJ5s/6/

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. But the effect I want is not the one you gave.

Comment: The image should wipe in from right to left. Please see the solution given by lnrbob. That was the effect I was looking for. But I will be using your solution also in the project. :-)

Comment: Please see http://jsfiddle.net/g8zDk/ . This was what I was looking. But will be using your solution too at another point. So I will have to include the UI library when I use your effect right

Comment: @LSDeveloper yes you need jQuery UI, with jQuery ui you can include just a part of the library so thatyou avoid to load a lot of functions that you don't use